# jVectorMap custom map border box

Tags: javascript, svg, bounding-box, jvectormap

I've created my own custom map with the SVG tool from jVectorMap (http://svgto.jvectormap.com). It displays correctly, but I want it to work with latitudes and longitudes, because I use the google maps API to position the markers on the map. I know it's possible with a bounding box, but I can't seem to get the bounding box values right. The markers do show up, but the location of the markers are far off.

How do I get these values?

Comment: you have to use in map.js file insets and bbox with x,y coordinates and also the projection method and central meridian for your map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `latLngToPoint` and `pointToLatLng`. But your map needs to have details about the used projection and insets, otherwise you'll get an error when trying to access these methods:

[jVectorMap Map format reference](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/map-format-reference/):

> projection
>       This parameter is required in case you want to plot the markers on the map by latitude and longitude

Also, see [this example](http://jvectormap.com/examples/reverse-projection/) (which is a bit buggy and doesn't work in FireFox).